# react native background Geolocation compile time error

Tags: react-native

I am using [react-native-background-geolocation](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation) package. I am getting an error in `gradle file`

> react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
>       Full recompilation is required because at least one of the classes of removed jar 'classes.jar' requires it. Analysis took 0.033 secs.
>       /home/ubuntu/code/truck-kothay-apps/truck-driver-app/node_modules/react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation/android/lib/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/data/BackgroundActivity.java:22:
>   error: cannot access AbstractSafeParcelable
>               confidence = actitivy.getConfidence();
>                                    ^
>         class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable
>   not found
>       Note: /home/ubuntu/code/truck-kothay-apps/truck-driver-app/node_modules/react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation/android/lib/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/BackgroundGeolocationFacade.java
>   uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>       Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>       Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>       Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>       1 error
>       :react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
>   FAILED
>
> ```
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check MainApplication.java file, check if

> new BackgroundGeolocationPackage()
>   is there.
>   After that make these changes in app/build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"


compile(project(':react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-location'
    }
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'
```

Rebuild the project after that and see.